# How to upload video in yii2 framework

Tags: video, yii2

When I try to upload a video, I'm receiving the following error:

> Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission.

**My Controller code:**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Videos();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {


      $videoName = "video_".rand();
        $model->video = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'video');

        if(!empty($model->video)){      
            $model->video->saveAs('../themes/light/images/video/'.$videoName.'.'.$model->video->extension);
            $model->video = 'themes/light/images/video/'.$videoName.'.'.$model->video->extension;
        }
       $model->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**My form:**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'video')->fileInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'date')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>
```

**My model:**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['video', 'title'], 'required'],
            [['videof'], 'file','extensions' => 'mp4','maxSize' => '2048000'],
            [['created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['video', 'title', 'date'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
```

I've never written a program to upload videos before. I don't know if any configuration needs to be made in a file. Please help me with this.

Comment: Do you close the form?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have typo in your code, You receive **video** as file but in your rules you have set file to field **videof**